# MobileServiceClient with different Model name than table name

Tags: c#, attributes, azure-mobile-services

Is there a way in Xamarin using MobileServiceClient to add an attribute to the class name to have a different table name?

i.e

```
this._client = new MobileServiceClient("myurl");
this._blogTable = _client.GetTable<Blog>();
```

But the table on the server is `XCHX_Blogs`

I would like to have my model class something like this

```
[TableName("XCHX_Blogs")]
public class Blog {
   ...
}
```

I cant seem to find a way to do this mapping in Xamarin forms (in the model).

Comment: This is not really a Xamarin.Forms question, right? You can use `MobileServiceClient` independently. Could you please remove the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do exactly what you are asking you'd have to pull the Mobile Service Client SDK source into your app (instead of using the Nuget) so that you could use the `internal` `MobileServiceTable<T>` constructor directly:

```
this._blogTable = new MobileServiceTable<Blog>("XCHX_Blogs", this._client);
```

Alternatively you can use the non-generic MobileServiceTable, but then you'll have to handle the JSON de/serialization:

```
this._blogTable = _client.GetTable("XCHX_Blogs");
var blog = new Blog();
await this._blogTable.InsertAsync(JObject.FromObject(blog));
```

Comment: This is really nice to know, i kind of cheated, i used an empty model called XCHC_Blogs that inherits from Blog, so when i pull the data i use the empty model and when returning it i return a Blog instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataContractAttribute or JsonContainerAttribute or DataTableAttribute

```
[DataContractAttribute(Name = "tableName")]
public class MyClass { ... }
IMobileServiceTable<MyClass> table = client.GetTable<MyClass>();
```

or

```
[JsonObjectAttribute(Title = "tableName")]
public class MyClass { ... }
IMobileServiceTable<MyClass> table = client.GetTable<MyClass>();
```

or

```
[DataTableAttribute("tableName")]
public class MyClass { ... }
IMobileServiceTable<MyClass> table = client.GetTable<MyClass>();
```

Personaly, I prefer the last solution because naming is coherent with type of objects.